# How to add a chat window?

Tags: dashboard-widgets

I have html code to add a chat window feature but I don't know where to input the code to get it to show up on the website.

Comment: Are you trying to add a chat window to the front-end of the site, for customers? Or are you trying to have it show up in the control panel, for content editors?

Comment: On a front end of a website for my customers to use.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you could just use a normal Twig template.

Comment: Would this help your for your problem?: https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/#template-paths

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could put just put that code into a normal Twig template.

If it's a JavaScript snippet, you can place it in the footer like this...

```js
{% js %}
    // Your JS goes here
{% endjs %}
```